# Center Point On Line in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have a line feature. I need to create a point feature from it. The point should ideally fall at the center of the line.

I used both CenterPointReplacer and CenterOfGravityReplacer but in some situations the point do not fall on the line. It is at some distance from the line which is not desirable. The picture below illustrators undesirable situation.

[image]

As you can see in the picture the point is not on the line. Is there transformer or a way to correct this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use snipper using percentage distance 50/50 . it will give you a point in the center of your lines.

[image]

Comment: Careful if you have arcs or pure curves http://fme-memorandum-takashi.blogspot.com/2013/12/middle-point-of-curve.html

Answer (score 0):

The Method that works best for this, from what I have found is to use a LabelPointReplacer followed immediately by a GeometryPartExtractor.

[image]

You can pick whatever attribute you want for the label and set the height to whatever because the label will be ignored by the GeometryPartExtractor.

In the GeometryPartExtractor, set it so that the part being extracted is the point.

Part to T...: This Part | Left Value: Geometry Type | Operator: = | Right Value: IFMEPoint

[image]

This works well because the LabelPointReplacer places the label on a line EXACTLY halfway along the line between the 2 endpoints.  The GeometryPartExtractor removes everything about the label, except for the point leaving only the point exactly halfway "on" the line allowing you to use it for whatever you need it for.  As the image below shows, it is exactly on the line.

[image]